# issue regarding getting user data in linkedin

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

actually i am using  OAuth 2.0. and used class of afnetworking, displayed Linkedin login page by using webview giving url as a client key and their authorization end Point,response type and state. everything is working

```
-(void)requestforAccessToken:(NSString *)authorisationCode
{
    NSString *grantType = @"authorization_code";

    NSString *postParameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=%@&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",grantType,authorisationCode,encodedRdirectURL,linkedInKey,linkedInSecret];

    NSData *postdata = [postParameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenEndPoint]];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = postdata;
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];


    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
        serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse  * response, id  responseObject, NSError * error )
      {
          if (!error)
          {
              NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

              NSString *accessToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];

              NSLog(@"Access Token %@",accessToken);


              NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

              [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"linkedInAccessToken"];

              [defaults synchronize];
          }

      }] resume];

}
```

By using this method i get Access token now my question is How to get user data like profile pic and all basic data. is thhere is any solution like facebook, just append accesstoken and u will get JSON data. Even i don't want to use SDK of linkedin , want direct communication so Please help. Thank You

Comment: What does the official LinkedIn documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the URL I use to get all possible informations from a LinkedIn user (without partnership with LinkedIn) :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,id,industry,location,headline,specialties,current-share,summary,picture-url,email-address,positions)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken]
```

The `accessToken` is the one you just get right after authentification.

Just make a `GET` request with `AFNetworking` on this URL and you'll receive, as you said, a JSON reply which looks like this :

```
{
    emailAddress = "****@gmail.com";
    firstName = Pi***e;
    headline = "Developpeur iOS chez Pi****e";
    id = 6Z***bFH3;
    industry = "Computer Software";
    lastName = "Test Account";
    location =     {
        country =         {
            code = fr;
        };
        name = "Paris Area, France";
    };
    pictureUrl = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_Gs*****U-9SswsbZKo3J*********eyCoHgYQadNFGRWQDyCwHjBVSdN4dVyw6gBFGIuQ3ZGnWmtsSdZUTjhIXErcmklEA7X";
    positions =     {
        "_total" = 1;
        values =         (
                        {
                company =                 {
                    name = Pi****e;
                };
                id = 823***52;
                isCurrent = 1;
                location = {
                };
                title = "Developpeur iOS";
            }
        );
    };
}
```